# runtime.futex taking 50% to 70% time in go profile

Tags: profiling, goroutine, channel, locks, futex

As part of profiling couple of golang services we are seeing that all the services are spending 55% to 70% time in the runtime.futex function.

Note that these services involve use of goroutines, locks, and channels for synchronization and communication between the goroutines.

Is this expected and we should only care about the time spent in the non-"runtime" functions or could this be an artifact of incorrect usage of goroutines/locks/channels that is causing this overhead in the futex call?

```
(pprof) top20
Showing nodes accounting for 43.80s, 80.25% of 54.58s total
Dropped 654 nodes (cum <= 0.27s)
Showing top 20 nodes out of 156
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    31.05s 56.89% 56.89%     31.05s 56.89%  runtime.futex
     3.55s  6.50% 63.39%      4.51s  8.26%  runtime.cgocall
     2.25s  4.12% 67.52%      2.25s  4.12%  runtime.usleep
     1.14s  2.09% 69.60%      1.53s  2.80%  runtime.scanobject
     0.73s  1.34% 70.94%      1.56s  2.86%  syscall.Syscall
     0.71s  1.30% 72.24%      2.27s  4.16%  runtime.mallocgc
```

```
(pprof) top20
Showing nodes accounting for 12.49s, 95.93% of 13.02s total
Dropped 93 nodes (cum <= 0.07s)
Showing top 20 nodes out of 47
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
     9.69s 74.42% 74.42%      9.69s 74.42%  runtime.futex
     1.25s  9.60% 84.02%      1.63s 12.52%  runtime.cgocall
     0.64s  4.92% 88.94%      0.64s  4.92%  runtime.usleep
     0.17s  1.31% 90.25%      0.22s  1.69%  runtime.timeSleepUntil
     0.11s  0.84% 91.09%      0.17s  1.31%  runtime.scanobject
     0.08s  0.61% 91.71%      0.08s  0.61%  runtime.nanotime1
     0.08s  0.61% 92.32%      0.26s  2.00%  runtime.retake
     0.07s  0.54% 92.86%      0.07s  0.54%  runtime.lock2
     0.07s  0.54% 93.39%      0.13s     1%  runtime.traceEventLocked
     0.06s  0.46% 93.86%      0.36s  2.76%  runtime.notetsleep_internal
     0.05s  0.38% 94.24%      0.13s     1%  runtime.mallocgc
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not unusual for a program that isn't doing very much.  If your program is spending most of time waiting for something to happen, it will often be sleeping in a futex.

Comment: Thank you Ian. Had a quick follow-up. What you say seems to make sense as when I increase the workload I do see one of the main go routines start to use comparable time as futex. Still the percentage ratio remains 40% for this main go routine, 36% for futex (which is significant), and the rest for others. Should I understand that there are many other go routines, in which the program is "waiting for something to happen" ? Also, is the time spent in futex counted against this process and hence idle CPU usage by the process that should be avoided by proper implementation of go routines.

Comment: Assuming you are on Linux, the futex use is CPU time counted against the process, but most likely the process isn't using much CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

FYI:

I had faced the same problem. In my case, I had a worker pool implementation. In which 200 goroutines were listening on to the same channel which in turn caused the contention. Then I used 1 channel per goroutine and which reduced runtime.futex very much.